# How to pass url parameter to reverse_lazy in Django urls.py

Tags: django, django-urls

Consider that I have 1 resource and 2 urls (let's say new one and old one) connected to that resourse. So, i want to setup HTTP redirection for one of urls.

In `myapp/urls.py` I have:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<param>\d+)/resource$', 
                      'myapp.views.resource', 
                       name='resource-view'
    ),
)
```

In `mycoolapp/urls.py` I want to specify:

```
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^coolresource/(?P<param>\d+)/$', 
                       redirect_to, 
                       {
                          'url': reverse_lazy('resourse-view', 
                                         kwargs={'param': <???>}, 
                                         current_app='myapp'
                                 ),
                       }
   ),
)
```

The question is how to pass `<param>` to the `reverse_lazy` kwargs (so, what to put instead of `<???>` in the example above)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the possible solutions of the general problem is to use hard-coded url pattern instead of `reverse_lazy` ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-redirect-to))

```
url(r'^coolresource/(?P<param>\d+)/$', 
                       redirect_to, 
                       {'url': '/%(param)s/resource'}
),
```

But, I don't like it so much, since it makes me harder after to do possible changes in urls.

Comment: documentation link? page not found

Comment: @grgizem the post created half a year ago .. sorry. Anyway, i've updated the link

Answer (score 32):

I wouldn't do this directly in the `urls.py`, I'd instead use the class-based `RedirectView` to calculate the view to redirect to:

```
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

class RedirectSomewhere(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, param):
        return reverse_lazy('resource-view',
                            kwargs={'param': param},
                            current_app='myapp')
```

Then, in your `urls.py` you can do this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^coolresource/(?P<param>\d+)/$', 
        RedirectSomewhere.as_view()),
)
```

Comment: scroll down to the solution using `pattern_name`, that's the correct solution for Django 1.6 and later

Answer (score 7):

Redirect View is great if you are using a hard coded url, it replaced redirect_to which is now deprecated. I don't think you can use it when redirecting and reversing from urls.py.  Here is my solution, x is the response object in this case:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ....
    url(r'^coolresource/(?P<param>\d+)/$',
                         lambda x, param: HttpResponseRedirect(
                             reverse('myapp.views.resource', args=[param])
                         ),
                         name='resource-view-redirect'),
    ....
)
```

You can still use the name of the url pattern instead of a hard coded url with this solution.  The location_id parameter from the url is passed down to the lambda function.

Comment: This is the cleverest solution here

Answer (score 6):

As of Django 1.6 you can do this ([Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.RedirectView.pattern_name)):

```
...
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^coolresource/(?P<param>\d+)/$', 
         RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='resource-view'),
    ),
)
```

Comment: How does this work if you want to pass args or kwargs to the pattern?

Comment: @Flimm this answer might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/12150035/742390

Answer (score 1):

You can't know or get what the value is until the view is called, so calculate `url` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Django's regex matching method for urls allows one to define and assign variables:

(`?P<variable_name>...)` defines `variable_name` depending on the `uri` being called; so what you need to put is: `param` instead of `<???>`